# Live resizing of an ext3 filesytem on CentOS6.5

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, resize2fs, cpanel

I have a problem with my remote server hosted by my provider, I have only SSH access. The problem consist of getting this error **file system rootfs has reached critical status** that causes problems with several services like smtp, I want to resize my partitions.
I want to:
- Decrease size of /home
- Increase the size of /

Is it possible to do that? is yes how to do that without losing my data and my CentOS installation?

```
root@web [~]# df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs         rootfs     20G   16G  3.4G  82% /
/dev/root      ext3       20G   16G  3.4G  82% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs   16G  256K   16G   1% /dev
/dev/md3       ext3      1.8T  137G  1.6T   8% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs      16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/loop0     ext3      510M   22M  463M   5% /tmp
/dev/loop0     ext3      510M   22M  463M   5% /var/tmp

root@web [~]# findmnt
TARGET                       SOURCE     FSTYPE   OPTIONS
/                            /dev/root  ext3     rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,u
├─/dev                       devtmpfs   devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=16419940k,nr_i
│ ├─/dev/pts                 devpts     devpts   rw,relatime,mode=600
│ └─/dev/shm                 tmpfs      tmpfs    rw,relatime
├─/proc                                 proc     rw,relatime
│ └─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc            binfmt_m rw,relatime
├─/sys                                  sysfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/home                      /dev/md3   ext3     rw,relatime,errors=continue,use
├─/tmp                       /dev/loop0 ext3     rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,error
└─/var/tmp                   /dev/loop0 ext3     rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,error
```

Comment: are you confident that reducing the size of /home (/dev/md3) will give you more space for your rootfs (/dev/root)?

Comment: Probably better to move some stuff from your root filesystem to your /home filesystem. It would be useful to list the partition table (`fdisk -l`), but reducing /home (which IIRC can't be done online) will not give any space to grow the root filesystem, as you need space at the end of the current root filesystem.

Comment: I found this link: https://codesilence.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/live-resizing-of-an-ext4-filesytem-on-linux/ may be it resolve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment on Anthon's answer, I think the *actual* solution to your problem may be to [tighten down your OS's `logrotate` configuration](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-centos-part-1).

While it is possible to move `/var/log` per Anthon's answer, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: for partitions resizing have you any solution to do that?

Comment: @linuxcdeveloper: Online shrink and resize is difficult even when you can do it offline, via a boot CD. Doing it on a remote VPS is far more difficult than it's worth. Whenever I have been faced with such a situation, I back everything up, create a new VPS account, restore everything, test, and then cut over to the new account via a DNS change.

Comment: @linuxcdeveloper: That said, 20 GiB for your root FS is probably sufficient. I would try to find the pigs sucking up all the space and either move them per Anthon's answer, or prevent them from sucking up as much space, per mine. There's no reason you should legitimately need to store more than 5-ish gigs of stuff in the root filesystem, and that mostly in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 3):

With 3.4 Gb free on root I don't think the free space is cause of the critical status. If you want to make space free on your root filesystem anyway, it is much more easy to copy some of the data to a special directory under `/home` and soft-link the original location to that copied data.

Move the original location out of the way, then link in a one-liner, then remove the originals, to minimize access problems.

Comment: I tried to remove some log files from /var/log, this error disappears but it re-appears when log files are reproduced from all services running on the server

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try to activate logrotate and to move log folder to /home and make symbolic link in /var to the new folder

Comment: @linuxcdeveloper I am still not sure why you get that message with 3.4 Gb free. There should also be a place where this can be set (absolute treshold or percentage), but I have not been able to find it.